# system.reflection dnlib issues

Tags: c#, .net, dnlib

im relatively new to working with dnlib and ive been trying to make a .NET packer & unpacker, but whenever i try and create a method that unpacks the assembly using Assembly.Load it throws an error something along the lines of 'unable to find X module'. the instructions im using to create this method write the following lines into the module:

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(Convert.FromBase64String("bytes"));
assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[0]);

is it possible to use Assembly.Load with this or is there something similar that recreates the same effect?